# win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') no longer working

Tags: python, win32com

The code no longer does anything to select the open workbook. I read through a bunch of older posts that used the "gencache.EnsureDispatch" to force it to work when "Dispatch" alone was no longer working. This not working seems to be tied to updating to Excel 2019 (prior 2016).

Any ideas?

Full Code:

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
print("Active WB:", excel.ActiveWorkbook.Name)
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
export_folder = export_folder.replace('/', '\\')
excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename = export_folder + filename, FileFormat = 6)
excel.Application.Quit() #close out all excel windows
excel.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Add this line to your code: `print('Cache directory:',win32com.client.gencache.GetGeneratePath())` And then go to this location and delete any directories in that folder. This will force win32com to recreate the bindings.

Comment: @DS_London Thank you, I've done this several times but still run into the same issue. It just doesn't do anything.

Comment: What you wrote will open a new instance of Excel.  Are you trying to connect to an instance that's already running?  Are you now running Office 365, or is this standalone Office?  It's true that the Office 365 versions are somewhat different.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am trying to connect to an instance that's already running. Running Office 2019. I used to run 2016 prior to an update, and the code worked fine. I tried opening the file specifically, but get an error during the SaveAs:

AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x2688700780352>' object has no attribute 'SaveAs'

Comment: The error says you tried to call `Application.SaveAs`, but you need `Workbook.SaveAs`, like you have in your second snippet.

Comment: Your code doesn't quite make sense. You are quitting Excel, and then trying to invoke the DisplayAlerts method on this now-defunct interface?

Comment: @TimRoberts the code below worked for a bit, but will not work this morning. I cleared the win32com directories again, but still not fixed. Any idea why it won't select the active workbook? Is there another way I could try to select it?

Comment: If you have the pathname of the open file, you can use `win32com.client.GetObject` to fetch the open instance.  http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/attach-to-a-com-instance.html

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't have a file name, unfortunately. Is there a way I can use a partial file name?